# CPU usage is higher than expected to be possible (over 200% with a total of two cores)

Tags: macos, cpu, cpu-usage

Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179820/top-command-how-come-cpu-in-process-is-higher-than-in-overall-cpu-usage-percen) and [this question](https://www.quora.com/What-does-100-CPU-utilization-mean), I understand that the percentage of CPU used can easily go up to `100 * number of processors * number of cores per processor` without affecting performance too badly; *e.g* if I have one processor with two cores, my CPU usage should be able to go easily to 200%.

I just checked with `top` while training a small neural network in Python / [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), and Python is consistently using over 300% of my single, dual core processor.

I have not been noticing any poor performance in any other applications. How is this possible?

[image: MacBook Pro specifications]

[image: Top]

Comment: If you run this in the Terminal it will tell you how many CPU cores you have including HyperThreading if present `sysctl -a hw.logicalcpu`

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSetchell, that explains a lot! (there are 4 cores available)

Comment: You can also get the Intel CPU model with `sysctl -a machdep.cpu.brand_string` and Google its spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your particular CPU supports multiple logical threads per physical core by some other mechanism. [This question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-know-how-many-threads-per-core-a-processor-has) suggests some ways you could discover if this is the case.

With the caveat that I'm kind of guessing, another reason you might see this effect is with Intel's Turbo Boost feature interacting with the way CPU counters and CPU usage are reported.

The `100% * nCores` thing breaks down in the presence of things like hyper-threading, CPU frequency scaling, and the murky relationship between what CPU vendors market as "threads" vs. "cores".

Comment: Thanks to @MarkSetchell, turns out I've got 4 cores when including HyperThreading (as shown by `sysctl -a hw.logicalcpu`), which explains things.